# Working with number basic type and indexOf in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, indexof, type-hinting

How can I get indexOf to play nice with TypeScript number basic type, now it is alway returning -1 even if it does exist?

On the **SelectElement** class I have a property "extra" containing an object with a key called "when" which is an array of numbers as defined on the **SelectElementInterface**.

Now on the **SelectElement** class, I also have property value which is also of type number.

But when running the code in the **displayExtra** method on the **SelectElement** class I am running into an issue regarding indexOf. The outputs of the console logs look like the following

```
[16:28:20]  console.log: [1,2]
[16:28:20]  console.log: 1
[16:28:20]  console.log: -1
```

As you can see from the console logs the value does exist and they should be of the same type according to my interface. Is this a bug in TypeScript or am I missing something here and how can I get indexOf to work with the basic number type in TypeScript?

**SelectElement class**

```
export class SelectElement extends Element<number> {
    public options: object;
    public extra: SelectElementInterface;

    constructor(options: ElementInterface, selectOptions: object, extra: SelectElementInterface) {
        super(options);
        this.options = selectOptions;
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public displayExtra(): boolean {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.extra.when));
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log(this.extra.when.indexOf(this.value));

        return this.extra.when.indexOf(this.value) > -1;
    }
}
```

**The element super class**

```
export abstract class Element<type> {

    public id: number;
    public type: string;
    public label: string;
    public required: boolean;
    public value: type;

    constructor(options: ElementInterface) {
        this.id = options.id;
        this.type = options.type;
        this.label = options.label;
        this.required = options.required;
    }

    abstract displayExtra(): boolean;
}
```

**ElementInterface**

```
export interface ElementInterface {
    id: number,
    type: string,
    label: string,
    required: boolean,
    value: string
}
```

**SelectElementInterface**

```
export interface SelectElementInterface  {
    input: string,
    label: string,
    required: boolean,
    when: Array<number>,
    value: string
}
```

**Edit:** Removed typos and code not necessary to the example.

Comment: Please consider making a better [MCVE], since that shows a lot of code that is not actually relevant to your problem.

Comment: Still not really sure what you're trying to achieve. It would be helpful if you can provide a sample to run the code, e.g. a test of some sort that calls the displayExtra() function. And that you can explain a bit what your expected outcome of the displayExtra() function is.

Comment: I suspect that the `value` property is not a number at runtime (try adding `console.log(this.value === 1);` to the body of `displayExtra()`.  Since you are not showing where `this.value` is being set, you have not provided enough information to answer this question.  If it is being set in TypeScript, I'd expect it to warn you that you were setting an invalid value to a `number` variable.  If it is being set in pure JavaScript then there's nothing TypeScript can do to help, since types are erased at runtime.  In either case I very much doubt the issue is with TypeScript or `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

You call super(options) but I don't see value being set anywhere in the constructor:

```
constructor(options: ElementInterface) {
  this.id = options.id;
  this.type = options.type;
  this.label = options.label;
  this.required = options.required;
  // Should this be set here?
  // this.value == options.value
}
```

Comment: the value of the elements are set in my angular components, but yeah I could remove that line and the code should still work. Thanks for pointing that out.